# Angular 4/5 problems

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, client

I wrote a connection interface between the server side and the client and when it worked I wanted to split it and work according to the correct architecture, once I changed the order and sorted folders I get the following message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) zone.js:388 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found)
>   loading http://localhost:3000/src/app/modules/app.module  Error: XHR
>   error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:3000/src/app/modules/app.module
>         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn

Since everything was under APP, I sorted them into -
App -
* modules
* components
* services

Comment: Moving the files around you probably changed the place of `app.module` and now it can't be found. You probably just need to change the URL accordingly.

Comment: I also realized that he could not reach him but I updated him the position at main, and the truth was that before I did that he did not even run the npm start command.
I currently do not know where else I need to update or declare his position, every threshold I put it into the mudoles folder